# ARCH Model: Which part does AR refer to?

Tags: garch

My background is signal processing and I am fairly new to (financial) time series analysis. I was reading the article about autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity (ARCH) models on Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity

I am confused about what AR (I know it means autoregressive :-) ) refers to in an ARCH model.
There are two possibilities in my view:

1.) The process of interest (and not its volatility), e.g., log-returns, is assumed to follow an AR-model:
$$ y_t = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^p y_{t-i} a_i   $$

2.) We assume that the volatility of the process we want to model (e.g., the above mentioned log-returns) follows an AR process.

The introduction section in Wikipedia seems to support my first hypothesis: 
"The ARCH model is appropriate when the error variance in a time series follows an autoregressive (AR) model..."

What confuses me though is this formula:

$$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^q \alpha_i \epsilon_{t-i}^2$$

I don't see the "autoregression" here...
Wouldn't and AR be something like:

$$\sigma_t^2 = \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^q \alpha_i \sigma_{t-i}^2$$.

This would then be a special case what is referred to as GARCH model.

Comment: The line just above your second to last quote from the Wiki article says $\epsilon_t=\sigma_t z_t$

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure though what you want to say by that.
Do you mean that this implies that the second moments are the same?
$$E[\epsilon_t^2] = E[\sigma_t^2 z_t^2] = E[\sigma_t^2].$$
Is the ARCH model not a generative model?

Answer (score 1):

In the following, what you call sigma is called h. So because you can write e(t) as a function of h(t) and a random variable z(t), when you write h(t) as a function of the past of e(t) you are equivalently writing out an autoregressive process for the error.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't  you need to regress on $h_{t-1}, h_{t-2}, ...$ to have the variance be an AR process?